# Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain in new Flutter project

Tags: java, android, flutter, visual-studio-code, gradle

I'm trying to run a new Flutter project, but I keep getting the following error message:

Copy
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain

I've tried creating a new Flutter project, but the error still persists. I'm not sure if this is relevant, but my SDK is in another folder.[image] I don't have any problems creating and running other projects like Kotlin with Android Studio.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error message says this seems to be related to your gradle. Clear cache or reinstall it.